# bash redirect in subcommand

Tags: bash, io-redirection

I'm stumped by an attempt at a bash redirect attempt.  I am trying to run a command that takes a redirect as a subcommand of `screen`, with the redirect going to the subcommand rather than to `screen`.

Here is a cleaned up version of the original command:

```
ssh -o "StrictHostKeyChecking no" <user>@<host> 'bash -s' < my_script.sh -- -s OPTION1 -o OPTION2
```

That works exactly as desired.  But, my attempt at running it under `screen` breaks:

```
screen -d -m ssh -o "StrictHostKeyChecking no" <user>@<host> 'bash -s' < my_script.sh -- -s OPTION1 -o OPTION2
```

I can see that now the redirect is going to `screen` rather than to `ssh`, but I can't figure out how to make it work the way I want it.

Comment: try this kind of piping: `screen -d -m << EOF` \n
`ssh -o "StrictHostKeyChecking no" <user>@<host> 'bash -s' < my_script.sh -- -s OPTION1 -o OPTION2`\n `EOF`

Comment: @blubase, ...normally I'd recommend that, but `screen` is something of a special case. Connecting stdin of a piece of software built to act as a terminal to a temporary file with contents you want to run in that terminal's child is far enough from its usual use case that I'd be worried about whether its developers would test the use case, or support it if it failed.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you have some working code, export it as a function, and call that function from inside your subshell started by `screen`. That way your code will run precisely as it would *without* screen involved.

```
#!/usr/bin/env bash
#              ^^^^- IMPORTANT: 'export -f' requires the parent and child shells to both
#                    persist functions in the environment in the same way. If the child is
#                    bash, the parent must be bash too!

option1=$1
option2=$2

runCommand() {
  [[ $user && $host ]] || { echo "ERROR: user and host not exported" >&2; return 1; }
  option1=$1; option2=$2
  printf -v cmd_str '%q ' -s "$option1" -o "$option2"
  ssh -o "StrictHostKeyChecking no" "${user}@${host}" \
    "bash -s -- $cmd_str" <my_script.sh
}
export -f runCommand

screen -d -m bash -c 'runCommand "$@"' _ "$option1" "$option2"
```

If your code uses variables you aren't showing us, be sure to `export` them too, so the exported function can access them.

Comment: Thanks.  So a further complication is that I'd like to specify OPTION1 and OPTION2 on the `screen` command line like so: `screen -d -m bash -c runCommand OPTION1 OPTION2`.  I just tried a runCommand() that just does `echo $1; echo $2`, but that doesn't seem to pick up the command line args.

Comment: If you want to pass arguments through, that would look more like `screen -d -m bash -c 'runCommand "$@"' _ "$@"`

Comment: ...note that passing arbitrary arguments _across ssh_ has its own challenges; a good solution will typically use something like `printf -v args_str '%q ' "$@"` to generate an `args_str` variable with a shell-quoted version of your argument list.